# Semantic elements work in IE 8 without html5shiv

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, semantic-markup, html5shiv

I'm building a website and need IE 8 support. I'm using HTML5 semantic elements (main, section, article, nav, header and footer).

I know these should NOT work in IE 8 so I included html5shiv.
And styled all elements as `display: block;`.

My layout was still a mess in IE 8 … so I added classes to all semantic elements and used those classes to style the elements in CSS.
Now the layout is correct AND I no longer seem to need the html5shiv.

Is this even possible? Can you style the semantic elements using classes without the use of html5shiv? If so, why use html5shiv?

```
nav {color: red}
```

does not work, but

```
<nav class="nav">
.nav {color: red}
```

does seem to work without html5shiv. Can someone confirm this?

EDIT:
After some careful testing I found out the following:

When having a SVG element on the page (which will not render in IE 8) the semantic elements can be styled with classes without the use of html5shiv.
This is very weird and probably some kind of bug in IE 8.

Comment: Googling html5shiv, "HTML5Shiv is a JavaScript workaround, created by Sjoerd Visscher, to enable styling of HTML5 elements in versions of Internet Explorer prior to version 9, which do not allow unknown elements to be styled without JavaScript."

Comment: I know what it is, but my point is that is seems totally unnecessary. Semantic elements do seem to work if styled correctly, at least in ie8?
I'm just wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: It seems if you don't use `document.createElement` with the tag name, the CSS engine in old IE versions doesn't know that kind of element exists and won't apply the styles to any of them if you try to use it in selectors, e.g. `nav {color: red;}` wouldn't work until after you `document.createElement('nav')`. Don't know if this has since been patched. Not sure about the behaviour if you manually add classes to everything, might be a valid workaround.

Comment: `nav{color: red}`  
indeed does not work, but 
`<nav class="nav"> .nav{color: red}`
does seem to work... can someone confirm this?